# Capture Error on Subscription Smart Button Integration with SDK - Both Sandbox and Live

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Case: Error when setting up a subscription via Smart Payment Buttons

Remark: In the Live environment I did get charged in my account for the transaction

Error: There is a capture error, and from 3 days of testing in both Sandbox AND Live cases there is not one solution found

For Sandbox Mode, I found a few references for the exact same error, but for those people it a. seems to have vanished overnight and 2. those weren't subscription models but regular purchase modes.
The following are the scripts and it shouldn't be that hard as I am making it, we set up a similar billing environment couple years ago and that worked almost immediately, that wasn't a subscription though.

Further details:
- I did setup the correct env settings as well in the composer files.
- Product is there
- Plan is there
- We use Seat based Pricing (0.01 cent and then we multiply the total amount in dollars *100)

```
////////////////////////////////////
// Error 500
////////////////////////////////////
```

// Via Console
POST https://www.paypal.com/smart/api/order/9VU587...34202/capture 500

// Via Network

{ack: "error", message: "Unhandled api error", meta: {calc: "4ac27dc9b8a70",…},…}

```
////////////////////////////////////
// Smart Button Script
////////////////////////////////////

<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?vault=true&client-id=<?= $paypal_sandbox_id ?>&currency=<?php echo $currency ?? "USD"; ?>&debug=false"></script>

<script>
paypal.Buttons({

    // Set up the subscription        
    createSubscription: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
            'plan_id': 'P-6NH76920JR31236564LYU3X4Y',
            'quantity': total_billed_vat * 100
        });
    },

    // Finalize the transaction
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        console.log('onApprove', data);

        // Authorize the transaction   
        return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
            console.log('capture', details);
            // Show a success message to the buyer 
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');

            // Call your server to save the transaction
            return fetch('../api/paypal/paypal-transaction-complete.php', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    orderID: data.orderID
                })
            });

        }).then(function (response) {
            // Show a success message to the buyer                            
            alert('actions.order.capture done ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
        });
    },
    onCancel: function (data, actions) {
        // Show a cancel page or return to cart
        alert('Feel free to retry when you are ready');
    }

}).render('#paypal-button-container');

</script>
```

The PHP Serverside Script:

```
////////////////////////////////////
// ../api/paypal/paypal-transaction-complete.php 
////////////////////////////////////

<?php
namespace Sample;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

//1. Import the PayPal SDK client that was created in `Set up Server-Side SDK`.
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersGetRequest;

class GetOrder
{

  // 2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
  /**
   *You can use this function to retrieve an order by passing order ID as an argument.
   */
  public static function getOrder($orderId)
  {

    // 3. Call PayPal to get the transaction details
    $client = PayPalClient::client();
    $response = $client->execute(new OrdersGetRequest($orderId));
    /**
     *Enable the following line to print complete response as JSON.
     */
    //print json_encode($response->result);
    print "Status Code: {$response->statusCode}\n";
    print "Status: {$response->result->status}\n";
    print "Order ID: {$response->result->id}\n";
    print "Intent: {$response->result->intent}\n";
    print "Links:\n";
    foreach($response->result->links as $link)
    {
      print "\t{$link->rel}: {$link->href}\tCall Type: {$link->method}\n";
    }
    // 4. Save the transaction in your database. Implement logic to save transaction to your database for future reference.
    print "Gross Amount: {$response->result->purchase_units[0]->amount->currency_code} {$response->result->purchase_units[0]->amount->value}\n";

    // To print the whole response body, uncomment the following line
    // echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  }
}

/**
 *This driver function invokes the getOrder function to retrieve
 *sample order details.
 *
 *To get the correct order ID, this sample uses createOrder to create a new order
 *and then uses the newly-created order ID with GetOrder.
 */

if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
{
  GetOrder::getOrder($data->orderID, true);
}
```

The SDK Used for v2 of the PayPal integration.

```
////////////////////////////////////
// SDK Installed in ../api/paypal/
////////////////////////////////////

{
    "require": {
        "paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

Used Manual Source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/
One of the Found Issue Resources: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/REST-APIs/BASIC-Smart-Payment-buttons-integration-help/td-p/1844051

Comment: Hi @Kim K. Im using the new Smart buttons but I'm getting the same error. Did you ever solved this issue?

Comment: @AndresSK sort of, i posted that in reply to Preston's reply to the post. Quote: I figured out that for the subscription model, the line "actions.order.capture()" is not accepted or well received. It seems the newer Smart Button logistics already take care of all that and just returns on an okay purchase. So far so good, tests are all returning positive results. Pending "real" transactions.

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of "500 Internal Service Error" API response that you're best off reaching out to PayPal's support for (MTS), rather than Stack Overflow, since it's effectively being thrown on the PayPal server end without details and needs to be traced back. However, I do happen to have some knowledge and in this case my suspicion would be that the transaction amount is not matching the purchase unit amount. Maybe this is something you can correct with a simpler request, i.e. test with a simple static number like $10 from start to finish and see if the problem does not occur.

Comment: thanks. I did also ask it there. That said: I figured out that for the subscription model, the line "actions.order.capture()" is not accepted or well received. It seems the newer Smart Button logistics already take care of all that and just returns on an okay purchase. So far so good, tests are all returning positive results. Pending "real" transactions. Thanks again.